# How can I apply jQuery.click to click first level of an item automaticlly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mmenu, jquery-click-event

I use this jquery menu lib for a sliding menu:http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

Live demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/p9ynx8wc/3/

It opens the menu and the sub-menu when I manually mouse click.

Now I want to open the menu and the submenu via jquery click; I can open the menu via jquery, but I cannot open the sub-menu.

Html of button that opens the sub-menu:

```
<li id="mmbasket">
    <a class="mm-next" href="#mm-1" data-target="#mm-1"></a>
    ... other elements ...
```

When I click the  manually, the sub-menu opens. (the  tag is generated automatically via MMENU JQUERY).

I wrote jquery code to click it automatically:

```
 var API = $("#menu").data( "mmenu" );

      $("#basket").click(function() {
          event.preventDefault(); 
         API.open();
         $('#mmbasket:first-child').click();
      });
```

The code opens the slide but not the sub-menu.

Visually:

[image]

Can somebody point out my mistake?

Comment: Use `trigger('click')`

Comment: @chet Not works. http://jsfiddle.net/p9ynx8wc/4/

Comment: @Chet `.click()` is the same as `.trigger("click")`. Read the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#mmbasket:first-child")` should be `$("#mmbasket > :first-child")`. Your selector matches `#mmbasket` if it **is** the first child of it's parent. You want the first child within `#mmbasket`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/p9ynx8wc/7/)